# Rails - best_in_place namespace controller is returning 404 when POST

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I followed the [#302 In-Place Editing screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/302-in-place-editing?view=asciicast) tutorial to implement best_in_place.

Views are located under `visitors`

So far, the editing works fine. However, it cannot retain changes after I press enter and I get a javascript error:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/visitors 404 (Not Found)
```

In my visitors/new.html.erb, I have implemented:

```
<%= best_in_place @visitor, :special %>
```

In my visitors_controller.rb, I have implemented:

```
class VisitorsController < ApplicationController

  respond_to :html, :json

  def show
    @visitor = Visitor.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @visitor = Visitor.new
  end

  def create
    @visitor = Visitor.new(secure_params)
    if @visitor.valid?
      @visitor.update_spreadsheet
      flash[:notice] = "Chose #{@visitor.favorite}."
      render :new
    else
      render :new
    end
  end


  def update
    @visitor = Visitor.find(params[:id])
    @visitor.update_attributes(secure_params)
    respond_with @visitor
  end

  private

  def secure_params
    params.require(:visitor).permit(:favorite, :comment)
  end
end
```

In my application.js, I have:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree ./bootstrap
//= require_tree ./styler
//= require social-media
//= require users
//= require jquery.purr
//= require best_in_place

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.best_in_place').best_in_place();
});
```

Any idea how to solve this problem? Please let me know if I need to provide further information.

**Edit:**

```
          Prefix Verb     URI Pattern                        Controller#Action
                 GET|POST /auth/:provider/callback(.:format) sessions#create
    auth_failure GET|POST /auth/failure(.:format)            redirect(301, /)
         signout GET|POST /signout(.:format)                 sessions#destroy
        supports POST     /supports(.:format)                supports#create
     new_support GET      /supports/new(.:format)            supports#new
menus_sandwiches GET      /menus/sandwiches(.:format)        menus#sandwiches
  menus_catering GET      /menus/catering(.:format)          menus#catering
 menus_breakfast GET      /menus/breakfast(.:format)         menus#breakfast
    menus_salads GET      /menus/salads(.:format)            menus#salads
 menus_smoothies GET      /menus/smoothies(.:format)         menus#smoothies
  menus_desserts GET      /menus/desserts(.:format)          menus#desserts
        visitors POST     /visitors(.:format)                visitors#create
     new_visitor GET      /visitors/new(.:format)            visitors#new
           menus POST     /menus(.:format)                   menus#create
        new_menu GET      /menus/new(.:format)               menus#new
            root GET      /                                  visitors#new
            page GET      /pages/*id                         high_voltage/pages#show
```

Comment: I don't see a params[:id] on that post request.  Are you creating a new visitor?  Or trying to update one?

Comment: Sorry, I just pasted the entire code for visitors_controller.rb. I'm trying to update the one.

Comment: Surprising you're getting a 404 - do you have a route for visitors#create?  What do you get when you do a `rake routes`?  Are you seeing that error in your rails logs?

Comment: Yes, I found this surprising as well. In fact, I do get visitors#create when I do a 'rake routes'.

Comment: You should see a POST /visitors url.  Can you post the results of rake routes?

Comment: Sure, I have posted the results of rake routes above.